# No HDMI Output on Raspberry Pi 2B

Tags: hdmi

I am a complete beginner, an have been having some issues with a Pi 2B.  I was helping my school librarian set up a message display.  I got a Pi, downloaded the OS, and used Etcher to put it on a USB drive.  The Pi turns on (I can see the light over PWR), but no output is detected by the monitor?  Did I do anything wrong?  I am generally technologically literate.

Answer (score 1):

You said "and used Etcher to put it on a USB drive". Did you mean SD card? Raspbian needs to be on a (micro) SD card, not a USB stick. See the official setup guide for more info: https://projects.raspberrypi.org/en/projects/raspberry-pi-setting-up